# Ubuntu start failed while using second monitor

Tags: 13.04, boot, multiple-monitors, laptop

Ubuntu 13.04

Laptop Asus UX32VD

If i connect monitor to my laptop ubuntu do not start properly. I see only black screen on both of displays. Magic SysRq do not reboot laptop. I only can shutdown laptop using long pressing power button.
Here is [syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6633088/) part, 11:14:53 time exactly before hot shutdown.

I'm connectiong using [this adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdLTK.jpg):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has same problems, the answer is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#External_Monitor).

There is no total solution of the problem.

> In case the user is "ready" pressing Fn+F8 before GRUB appears should
>   solve the dual screen problem as well ([according to reports on Ubuntu
>   and the Asus Zenbook thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865577)).

In this thread I found, that you should disconnect your second monitor while booting Ubuntu. Or as mentioned press Fn+F8 before GRUB appears.

Comment: Thanks for sharing where you found more information to solve your problem. Can you provide a bit more information what you did? Also [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.